# Request to my http page is getting re-directed to https

Tags: apache, http, web, https, dns

I have made a wordpress website on my desktop. I have the correct host port forwarding setup for both 80/443 ports. When I connect to my website using the http://external-ip I get sent to my site. However, when I use the DNS name: http://mywebsite it gets re-directed to https and I get a "refused to connect". Why is my http address getting redirected to https? I am using google domains for domain registration and DNS. The re-direction also happens on my phone etc. I ran tcpdump on port 80 and I see no traffic come in, so it is not my webserver that is redirecting http to https. Who could be doing it?

I tried using my external ip and that works correctly. When I use the DNS name that redirects to a https page which does not work because my webserver does not listen on https port.

I have tried clearing the site settings and browser cache, but this keeps happening. I also enabled "insecure content" for my website in chrome, and cleared the history/cache. It is still happening.

EDIT: this is what developer tools show:

Request Method:GET

Status Code:307 Internal Redirect

Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: insecure port is 80 = http and Secure port is 443 = https

Comment: What is your domain name?  I'll bet you have a `.dev` domain or some other top level domain that is in the HSTS preload list and doesn't support HTTP at all. See https://serverfault.com/a/1091612

Comment: As @StephenOstermiller suggested, my domain ends in .dev and it is in HSTS preload list. Thanks StephenOstermiller

Answer (score 0):

As @StephenOstermiller suggested, my domain ends in .dev and it is in HSTS preload list. Thanks StephenOstermiller